# I am using webrtc for video calling in android but I am getting html response instead of json my call url is "https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=111111"

Tags: android, webrtc

This is my AppRtcClient client. I am getting Fatal error:

> Value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject getParametersForRoomUrl(urls[0]) 
>   This line inside RoomParameterGetter class.

```
public class AppRTCClient {
private static final String TAG = "AppRTCClient";
private GAEChannelClient channelClient;
private final Activity activity;
private final GAEChannelClient.MessageHandler gaeHandler;
private final IceServersObserver iceServersObserver;
// These members are only read/written under sendQueue's lock.
private LinkedList<String> sendQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
private AppRTCSignalingParameters appRTCSignalingParameters;
/**
 * Callback fired once the room's signaling parameters specify the set of
 * ICE servers to use.
 */
public static interface IceServersObserver {
    public void onIceServers(List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers);
}
public AppRTCClient(Activity activity,
        GAEChannelClient.MessageHandler gaeHandler,
        IceServersObserver iceServersObserver) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.gaeHandler = gaeHandler;
    this.iceServersObserver = iceServersObserver;
}
/**
 * Asynchronously connect to an AppRTC room URL, e.g.
 * https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=NNN and register message-handling callbacks
 * on its GAE Channel.
 */
public void connectToRoom(String url) {
    while (url.indexOf('?') < 0) {
        // Keep redirecting until we get a room number.
        (new RedirectResolver()).execute(url);
        return; // RedirectResolver above calls us back with the next URL.
    }
    (new RoomParameterGetter()).execute(url);
}
/**
 * Disconnect from the GAE Channel.
 */
public void disconnect() {
    if (channelClient != null) {
        channelClient.close();
        channelClient = null;
    }
}
/**
 * Queue a message for sending to the room's channel and send it if already
 * connected (other wise queued messages are drained when the channel is
 * eventually established).
 */
public synchronized void sendMessage(String msg) {
    synchronized (sendQueue) {
        sendQueue.add(msg);
    }
    requestQueueDrainInBackground();
}
public boolean isInitiator() {
    return appRTCSignalingParameters.initiator;
}

public MediaConstraints pcConstraints() {
    return appRTCSignalingParameters.pcConstraints;
}
public MediaConstraints videoConstraints() {
    return appRTCSignalingParameters.videoConstraints;
}

public MediaConstraints audioConstraints() {
    return appRTCSignalingParameters.audioConstraints;
}
// Struct holding the signaling parameters of an AppRTC room.
private class AppRTCSignalingParameters {
    public final List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers;
    public final String gaeBaseHref;
    public final String channelToken;
    public final String postMessageUrl;
    public final boolean initiator;
    public final MediaConstraints pcConstraints;
    public final MediaConstraints videoConstraints;
    public final MediaConstraints audioConstraints;
    public AppRTCSignalingParameters(
            List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers, String gaeBaseHref,
            String channelToken, String postMessageUrl, boolean initiator,
            MediaConstraints pcConstraints,
            MediaConstraints videoConstraints,
            MediaConstraints audioConstraints) {
        this.iceServers = iceServers;
        this.gaeBaseHref = gaeBaseHref;
        this.channelToken = channelToken;
        this.postMessageUrl = postMessageUrl;
        this.initiator = initiator;
        this.pcConstraints = pcConstraints;
        this.videoConstraints = videoConstraints;
        this.audioConstraints = audioConstraints;
    }
}
// Load the given URL and return the value of the Location header of the
// resulting 302 response. If the result is not a 302, throws.
private class RedirectResolver extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        if (urls.length != 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Must be called with a single URL");
        }
        try {
            return followRedirect(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String url) {
        connectToRoom(url);
    }
    private String followRedirect(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected response: " + code + " for "
                    + url + ", with contents: "
                    + drainStream(connection.getInputStream()));
        }
        int n = 0;
        String name, value;
        while ((name = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(n)) != null) {
            value = connection.getHeaderField(n);
            if (name.equals("Location")) {
                return value;
            }
            ++n;
        }
        throw new IOException("Didn't find Location header!");
    }
}
// AsyncTask that converts an AppRTC room URL into the set of signaling
// parameters to use with that room.
private class RoomParameterGetter extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, AppRTCSignalingParameters> {
    @Override
    protected AppRTCSignalingParameters doInBackground(String... urls) {
        if (urls.length != 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Must be called with a single URL");
        }
        try {
            return getParametersForRoomUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AppRTCSignalingParameters params) {
        channelClient = new GAEChannelClient(activity, params.channelToken,
                gaeHandler);
        synchronized (sendQueue) {
            appRTCSignalingParameters = params;
        }
        requestQueueDrainInBackground();
        iceServersObserver
                .onIceServers(appRTCSignalingParameters.iceServers);
    }
    // Fetches |url| and fishes the signaling parameters out of the JSON.
    private AppRTCSignalingParameters getParametersForRoomUrl(String url)
            throws IOException, JSONException {
        url = url + "&t=json";
        JSONObject roomJson = new JSONObject(drainStream((new URL(url))
                .openConnection().getInputStream()));

        if (roomJson.has("error")) {
            JSONArray errors = roomJson.getJSONArray("error_messages");
            throw new IOException(errors.toString());
        }
        String gaeBaseHref = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));
        String token = roomJson.getString("token");
        String postMessageUrl = "/message?r="
                + roomJson.getString("room_key") + "&u="
                + roomJson.getString("me");
        boolean initiator = roomJson.getInt("initiator") == 1;
        LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = iceServersFromPCConfigJSON(roomJson
                .getString("pc_config"));

        boolean isTurnPresent = false;
        for (PeerConnection.IceServer server : iceServers) {
            if (server.uri.startsWith("turn:")) {
                isTurnPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isTurnPresent) {
            iceServers
                    .add(requestTurnServer(roomJson.getString("turn_url")));
        }
        MediaConstraints pcConstraints = constraintsFromJSON(roomJson
                .getString("pc_constraints"));
        addDTLSConstraintIfMissing(pcConstraints);
        Log.d(TAG, "pcConstraints: " + pcConstraints);
        MediaConstraints videoConstraints = constraintsFromJSON(getAVConstraints(
                "video", roomJson.getString("media_constraints")));
        Log.d(TAG, "videoConstraints: " + videoConstraints);
        MediaConstraints audioConstraints = constraintsFromJSON(getAVConstraints(
                "audio", roomJson.getString("media_constraints")));
        Log.d(TAG, "audioConstraints: " + audioConstraints);

        return new AppRTCSignalingParameters(iceServers, gaeBaseHref,
                token, postMessageUrl, initiator, pcConstraints,
                videoConstraints, audioConstraints);
    }
    // Mimic Chrome and set DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement to true if not set to false
    // by
    // the web-app.
    private void addDTLSConstraintIfMissing(MediaConstraints pcConstraints) {
        for (MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair pair : pcConstraints.mandatory) {
            if (pair.getKey().equals("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement")) {
                return;
            }
        }
        for (MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair pair : pcConstraints.optional) {
            if (pair.getKey().equals("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement")) {
                return;
            }
        }
        // DTLS isn't being suppressed (e.g. for debug=loopback calls), so
        // enable
        // it by default.
        pcConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(
                "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
    }

    // Return the constraints specified for |type| of "audio" or "video" in
    // |mediaConstraintsString|.
    private String getAVConstraints(String type,
            String mediaConstraintsString) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mediaConstraintsString);
            // Tricksy handling of values that are allowed to be (boolean or
            // MediaTrackConstraints) by the getUserMedia() spec. There are
            // three
            // cases below.
            if (!json.has(type) || !json.optBoolean(type, true)) {
                // Case 1: "audio"/"video" is not present, or is an explicit
                // "false"
                // boolean.
                return null;
            }
            if (json.optBoolean(type, false)) {
                // Case 2: "audio"/"video" is an explicit "true" boolean.
                return "{\"mandatory\": {}, \"optional\": []}";
            }
            // Case 3: "audio"/"video" is an object.
            return json.getJSONObject(type).toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private MediaConstraints constraintsFromJSON(String jsonString) {
        if (jsonString == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            MediaConstraints constraints = new MediaConstraints();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONObject mandatoryJSON = json.optJSONObject("mandatory");
            if (mandatoryJSON != null) {
                JSONArray mandatoryKeys = mandatoryJSON.names();
                if (mandatoryKeys != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mandatoryKeys.length(); ++i) {
                        String key = mandatoryKeys.getString(i);
                        String value = mandatoryJSON.getString(key);
                        constraints.mandatory
                                .add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(key,
                                        value));
                    }
                }
            }
            JSONArray optionalJSON = json.optJSONArray("optional");
            if (optionalJSON != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < optionalJSON.length(); ++i) {
                    JSONObject keyValueDict = optionalJSON.getJSONObject(i);
                    String key = keyValueDict.names().getString(0);
                    String value = keyValueDict.getString(key);
                    constraints.optional
                            .add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(key,
                                    value));
                }
            }
            return constraints;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    // Requests & returns a TURN ICE Server based on a request URL. Must be
    // run
    // off the main thread!
    private PeerConnection.IceServer requestTurnServer(String url) {
        try {
            URLConnection connection = (new URL(url)).openConnection();
            connection.addRequestProperty("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            connection.addRequestProperty("origin",
                    "https://apprtc.appspot.com");
            String response = drainStream(connection.getInputStream());
            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response);
            String uri = responseJSON.getJSONArray("uris").getString(0);
            String username = responseJSON.getString("username");
            String password = responseJSON.getString("password");
            return new PeerConnection.IceServer(uri, username, password);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
// Return the list of ICE servers described by a WebRTCPeerConnection
// configuration string.
private LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServersFromPCConfigJSON(
        String pcConfig) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(pcConfig);
        JSONArray servers = json.getJSONArray("iceServers");
        LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer> ret = new LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < servers.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject server = servers.getJSONObject(i);
            String url = server.getString("urls");
            String credential = server.has("credential") ? server
                    .getString("credential") : "";
            ret.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer(url, "", credential));
        }
        return ret;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
// Request an attempt to drain the send queue, on a background thread.
private void requestQueueDrainInBackground() {
    (new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        public Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            maybeDrainQueue();
            return null;
        }
    }).execute();
}
// Send all queued messages if connected to the room.
private void maybeDrainQueue() {
    synchronized (sendQueue) {
        if (appRTCSignalingParameters == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            for (String msg : sendQueue) {
                URLConnection connection = new URL(
                        appRTCSignalingParameters.gaeBaseHref
                                + appRTCSignalingParameters.postMessageUrl)
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.getOutputStream().write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                if (!connection.getHeaderField(null).startsWith(
                        "HTTP/1.1 200 ")) {
                    throw new IOException("Non-200 response to POST: "
                            + connection.getHeaderField(null)
                            + " for msg: " + msg);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        sendQueue.clear();
    }
}
// Return the contents of an InputStream as a String.
private static String drainStream(InputStream in) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
}
```

`

Comment: i am also facing the same probem in my Androis & IOS app.

Comment: I followed this [link](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/) and my problem is resolved now.